# Ruby query to find record between two dates works in console, but not in the View

Tags: ruby

Trying to display some records (model named Event in the app) using their @event.date to organize them.

In the console, I'm able to see them running this:

```
Event.where(:date => DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week)
```

Result in the console

```
Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ("events"."date" BETWEEN '2015-08-16 22:00:00.000000' AND '2015-08-23 21:59:59.000000')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, name: "My BBQ", description: "A BBQ with friends", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-21", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:06:54", updated_at: "2015-08-15 11:06:54">, #<Event id: 6, name: "BBQ on the 20", description: "Because weekly bbq", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-20", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:56:09", updated_at: "2015-08-15 11:56:09">, #<Event id: 8, name: "Birthday BBQ", description: "Because yes", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-19", created_at: "2015-08-15 12:17:19", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:17:19">, #<Event id: 5, name: "Sunday BBQ", description: "It will rain", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-17", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:46:44", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:21:15">, #<Event id: 9, name: "Test BBQ", description: "Testing", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-23", created_at: "2015-08-15 12:34:33", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:34:33">, #<Event id: 10, name: "Test num 2", description: "", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-22", created_at: "2015-08-15 12:35:23", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:35:23">]>
irb(main):051:0>
```

The view where I'm trying to render what outputs the console has this code:

```
    <% @events.each do |event| %>

        <% if event.date === DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week %>
            <% if event.accepted == 0 %>
                <div class="row eventrow">
                  <span class="eventlikes">↑9</span>
                  <a href="/events/<%= event.id %>"><span class="eventtitle"><%= event.name %> | <%= event.city %></span></a> On <%= event.date %>
                  <div class="eventgoers right">
                    <span class="">Submitted by</span><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Lpavq5s.png?1" class="individualeventgoer">
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% else %>
                <div class="row eventrow red">
                  <span class="eventlikes">↑9</span>
                  <a href="/events/<%= event.id %>"><span class="eventtitle"><%= event.name %> | <%= event.city %></span><span class="">Only visible to admin</span></a>On <%= event.date %>
                  <div class="eventgoers right">
                    <span class="">Submitted by</span><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Lpavq5s.png?1" class="individualeventgoer">
                  </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
        no events
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

But in the final View, I only manage to get 1 displayed, **why?**
[image]

**Note** that I have also tried adding a '.' to the query like:

Event.where(:date => DateTime.now.next_week...DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week), but the results is still not the expected one in the View.

In the console for that last query I get:

```
irb(main):051:0> Event.where(:date => DateTime.now.next_week...DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week)
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ("events"."date" >= '2015-08-16 22:00:00.000000' AND "events"."date" < '2015-08-23 21:59:59.000000')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, name: "My BBQ", description: "A BBQ with friends", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-21", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:06:54", updated_at: "2015-08-15 11:06:54">, #<Event id: 6, name: "BBQ on the 20", description: "Because weekly bbq", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-20", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:56:09", updated_at: "2015-08-15 11:56:09">, #<Event id: 8, name: "Birthday BBQ", description: "Because yes", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-19", created_at: "2015-08-15 12:17:19", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:17:19">, #<Event id: 5, name: "Sunday BBQ", description: "It will rain", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-17", created_at: "2015-08-15 11:46:44", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:21:15">, #<Event id: 10, name: "Test num 2", description: "", city: "Brussels", accepted: 0, date: "2015-08-22", created_at: "2015-08-15 12:35:23", updated_at: "2015-08-15 12:35:23">]>
irb(main):052:0>
```

And only **2** records in the View - Any help to understand why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't understand what `===` operator do. By using `...` you transform your DateTime objects to Range object:

```
(DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week).class
# => Range
```

Then you're trying to compare you range object with event.date:

```
<% if event.date === DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week %>
```

And of course it returns you `false`, since any date instance cannot be equal to any range instance. You should use [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) method to check if element lies into range:

```
if (DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week).cover?(event.date)
```

Comment: No - using Range#include? didn't render any record in the view. But maybe because Range is only for *objects* and I'm working with Dates here? I have tried with <% if (DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week).cover?(event.date) %> http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F and it seems to solve the issue, but still don't know why your suggested solution didn't work, and this one yes.

Comment: By using `...` operator you're creating Range object. You can check it by typing `(DateTime.now.next_week..DateTime.now.next_week.end_of_week).class`. Thats why your `===` doesn't work.

Comment: And about my solution. That's my fault, you should definetelly use `cover?`. The difference is that `include?` transform range to array and check if any array element equal to passed elem. But `cover?` try to compare your object with the borders of range object to check if it lies inside the range.